# Ruby Koans about_methods line 119 how to get error on a private method in IRB

Tags: ruby, methods, nomethoderror

I try to run this method in IRB and do not get anything. Just a new line for a new command. I understand that it's a private method, but I don't understand how people get the required error.

```
def my_private_method
    "a secret"
end
private :my_private_method
```

and expected result: **(NoMethodError)** and **/private method/**

```
def test_calling_private_methods_with_an_explicit_receiver
    exception = assert_raise(__) do
        self.my_private_method
    end
    assert_match /__/, exception.message
end
```

Comment: Mind pasting the command & result from `irb`?

Comment: In IRB, `Object.private_instance_methods(false) #=> [:DelegateClass, :default_src_encoding, :irb_binding, :my_private_method]`. From command line, `#=> [:DelegateClass, :my_private_method]`.

Comment: @aceofbassgreg 
    irb(main):003:0* def my_private_method
    irb(main):004:1>     "a secret"
    irb(main):005:1> end
    => :my_private_method
    irb(main):006:0> private :my_private_method
    => Object
    irb(main):007:0> my_private_method
    => "a secret"

Sorry for how this looks, I don't know how to format this to be more redible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are literally just pasting this method into an `irb` session without including it into a class, then you're defining the method within the scope of `Object`:

`2.2.1 :001 > def my_private_method
2.2.1 :002?>       "a secret"
2.2.1 :003?>   end
 => :my_private_method 
2.2.1 :004 > private :my_private_method
 => Object 
2.2.1 :005 > my_private_method
 => "a secret"`

The reason you can call the private method is because when you call the method, you are still within the scope of `Object`. This makes sense...you SHOULD be able to call a private method from within the same scope.

Private methods in a class may not be called by another class' instances. Here's an example that may help:

```
class PrivateMethodClass

  def my_private_method
    "a secret"
  end

  def puts_my_private_method
    puts my_private_method
  end

  private :my_private_method
end

class AnotherClass

  def that_private_method
    PrivateMethodClass.new.my_private_method
  end
end
```

Paste the above into `irb` and then create instances of each of these classes and try calling their methods. Note that `PrivateMethodClass` instances can call `:puts_my_private_method` and it will execute, but that `AnotherClass` instances cannot successfully call `:that_private_method`.